# Sending myself a test email via WFC Client Using C# and ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

So I started working on an app we have written in asp.net MVC and C#. We have an EmailSupport.cs file that contains a bunch of methods to return a new StringBuilder by AppendLine, AppendFormat, and Append. Literally each line is added in this way. The whole purpose of these methods is to receive quote data, and add the data we get to the html (appended) to be sent out as an email. 

I am really new to C# and asp.net, used to working with Javascript/React/Node.js all that, so I am completely lost on how to view this HTML as I make changed to see if it matches the new design files they want me to implement. ( they aren't using Razor with these ).
As far as I can tell they are using WCF to send the emails after they have been serialized, I can send myself a test email through the WCF Test Client, but cannot send it with the html data, the only thing I can put in the body is basic text like "hello test test"
So basically I need a way to see what I am doing as I am making changes, and send myself a test email with the HTML from the correct method so I can make sure it is working...
Any ideas?

So we do something like this:

```
public virtual string SendAutoQuotingInstantEmail(AutoQuote<AutoQuotePerson> quote, string emailTo, string baseUrl, string CSCNumber, string stateCode)
{
       CSSfile = baseUrl + "link to css here";
       emailSubject = "email subject here";
       headerImage = baseUrl + "link to headerimage";
       longCompanyName = "Full company name";
       shortCompanyName = "shorthand co name";
       agentLocatorLink = "link to agent locator";
       privacyStatementUrl = "link to privacy statement";
       mailingAddress = "address";

var html = new StringBuilder();

html.AppendLine("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");

            html.AppendLine("<html><head>");
            html.AppendFormat("<title>Your Auto Insurance Quote From {0}</title>", longCompanyName).AppendLine();
<..... more appends for days.....>


            var result = _quoteService.SendEmail(emailSubject, _emailFrom, _emailFrom, emailTo, html.ToString());
            EmailText = html.ToString();

            return result;
        }
```

WCF is using basicHttpBinding

Comment: This probably isn't something you can fix. It depends on the library that the remote service uses to create and send the email. For example, System.Net.Mail.MailMessage has an `IsBodyHtml` property. If the WCF service doesn't give you an option to specify whether it's HTML then it probably just always assumes the body is plain text. The change would have to be in that service, to allow you to specify that the content is HTML so that it sets that property.

Comment: @ScottHannen the only thing I can really see for the MailService we are using that pops out at me is UTILITYSoapClient?

Comment: It's somewhere in that quote service. So it's not even in your code. It's in the code of the WCF service on the other end. It doesn't look like that service gives you a way to specify an HTML body, which means you can't unless you modify that service or find a different way to send emails. I'd question why the quote service has anything to do with sending emails (instead of a service just for that) but I've seen/done pretty much the exact same thing so I know how it is.